what does "In general, ..." mean in the patent specification?
If a paragraph or a sentence either starts with or has "In general, ..." in it somewhere, what does it mean?

"In general" is a weasel phrase that is meant to avoid explicitly excluding other possibilities. In general, it's better to describe alternate embodiments and possibilities explicitly in order to expand the possible scope of patent claims. I don't think weasel phrases are given much legal effect.
